# Achieve iOS 7 UITableViewCell grouped style in iOS 6

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to "flatize" my app in iOS 6 and achieve the same look of an iOS 7 UITableView grouped, so I've subclassed UITableViewCell and applied this code:

```
-(void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame{
    if (self.superview) {
        if (!IS_IOS7){
            float cellWidth;

            if (IS_IPAD){
                cellWidth = 870;
            }
            else{
                cellWidth = 350;
            }
            frame.origin.x  = (self.superview.frame.size.width - cellWidth) / 2;
            frame.size.width = cellWidth;
        }
    }
    [super setFrame:frame];
}
```

It's working fine, but I have to manually adjust the inset of the cell in cellForRow method.

I tried setting the table plain, removed empty cells, but the header wasn't fixed, so I tried to set it as tableHeaderView but didn't work as expected because of the searchBar.

So, is there any better and cleaner way to achieve it that I'm missing?

Comment: Just to be sure I understand the look you want to achieve... it's something like the Settings app on iOS 7 yes? With space between sections, the thin line going full width at the top/bottom of sections, and the partial line between rows, or something like that?

Comment: Yeah, exactly like that. The only difference would be a custom header, which I already have.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how to make a UITableView look just like iOS 7 grouped style on both iOS 6 and 7. It's a very manual approach, but it looks spot on.

1) Make a UITableViewCell subclass. In the header, define an enum to handle the types of grouping positions. Plus a method to set the values.

```
- (void)setGroupedStyle:(MMTableViewCellGroupStyle)groupedStyle;

typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, MMTableViewCellGroupStyle) {
    MMTableViewCellGroupStyleSingle,
    MMTableViewCellGroupStyleTop,
    MMTableViewCellGroupStyleBottom,
    MMTableViewCellGroupStyleMiddle
};
```

2) In the UITableViewCell subclass, create UIView's for the cells according to their grouped styles. You'll need to create a custom UIView class that draws 1 pixel lines in `drawRect:`, aligning the color to top or bottom depending on the line position. You will also need to manually indent the lines for the bottom of the middle cells.

I whipped this up very quickly so it's not the cleaned most DRY code, but just so you get an idea. Also note I didn't create the UIView subclass to draw 1 pixel lines for retina devices, this just creates views with 1 point lines. An exercise left to the reader =)

```
#define CELL_LEFT_INSET 20.0f
- (void)setGroupedStyle:(MMTableViewCellGroupStyle)groupedStyle
{
    [self.lines makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
    switch (groupedStyle) {
        case MMTableViewCellGroupStyleSingle: {
            UIView *top = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.frame), 1.0f)];
            top.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;

            UIView *bottom = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, CGRectGetHeight(self.frame) - 1.0f, CGRectGetWidth(self.frame), 1.0f)];
            bottom.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;

            self.lines = @[top, bottom];
            break;
        }
        case MMTableViewCellGroupStyleTop: {
            UIView *top = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.frame), 1.0f)];
            top.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;

            UIView *bottom = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(CELL_LEFT_INSET, CGRectGetHeight(self.frame) - 1.0f, CGRectGetWidth(self.frame) - CELL_LEFT_INSET, 1.0f)];
            bottom.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;

            self.lines = @[top, bottom];
            break;
        }
        case MMTableViewCellGroupStyleMiddle: {
            UIView *bottom = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(CELL_LEFT_INSET, CGRectGetHeight(self.frame) - 1.0f, CGRectGetWidth(self.frame) - CELL_LEFT_INSET, 1.0f)];
            bottom.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;

            self.lines = @[bottom];
            break;
        }
        case MMTableViewCellGroupStyleBottom: {
            UIView *bottom = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, CGRectGetHeight(self.frame) - 1.0f, CGRectGetWidth(self.frame), 1.0f)];
            bottom.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;

            self.lines = @[bottom];
            break;
        }
    }
    for (UIView *line in self.lines) {
        line.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        [self addSubview:line];
    }
}
```

3) When you configure the cell in the `UITableViewDataSource`, set the appropriate groupStyle for each cell.

```
MMTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

if ([tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section] == 1) {
    [cell setGroupedStyle:MMTableViewCellGroupStyleSingle];
} else if (indexPath.row == 0) {
    [cell setGroupedStyle:MMTableViewCellGroupStyleTop];
} else if (indexPath.row == ([tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section] - 1)) {
    [cell setGroupedStyle:MMTableViewCellGroupStyleBottom];
} else {
    [cell setGroupedStyle:MMTableViewCellGroupStyleMiddle];
}
```

4) In the `UITableViewDataSource` return a good height for sectionFOOTERs. This will be the empty space between sections. Implement the method to return the footer view to return an empty UIView.

5) Make sure you are using sections for each grouped section. Add one extra section at the very top since you will need that extra space to lead up to the first section.